# パスの\(エスケープ)を/に置換する方法を教えてください

Tags: r, 正規表現

パスが指定されたときに指定されたパスの(エスケープ)を/に置換したいと思ってます。
例えば
C:\R\data\covid
を
C:/R/data/covid/
というように置換したいです。

以下のプログラムのように、gsub関数を使ってパスの(エスケープ)を/に置換しようとしましたが、エラーになってしまいました。

```
gsub("\\","/","C:\R\data\covid\")
エラー:  ""C:\R" で始まる文字列の中で '\R' は文字列で認識されないエスケープです
```

3番目の変数を書き換えず、置換する方法はありますか？(エラーの原因は3番目の変数に(エスケープ)があるからだと思ってますが、3番目の変数をそのまま使いたいです。）

補足
以下のプログラムは動くことを確認しています。

```
gsub("\\","/","C:\\R\\data\\covid\\", fixed=TRUE)
[1] "C:/R/data/covid/"
gsub("\\\\","/","C:\\R\\data\\covid\\")
[1] "C:/R/data/covid/"
```

Comment: "\r"は、カーソルを行の先頭に移動させる「キャリッジリターン(Carriage Return)」という制御文字です。だから、エラーメッセージの中で『C:\R" で始まる文字列の中で '\R' は文字列で認識されないエスケープです 』と説明されています。

Comment: [Error: '\R' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "C:\R"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12695879)

Answer (score 1):

R言語では（R言語以外でもC言語なども）バックスラッシュはエスケープシーケンスを意味します。
バックスラッシュ自体に特別な意味があるのです。
従いまして、”\”を表す場合”\\”と2つで表現します。
これはプログラムの中では”\”を意味します。
従って、

```
gsub("\\","/","C:\\R\\data\\covid\\", fixed=TRUE)
[1] "C:/R/data/covid/"
gsub("\\\\","/","C:\\R\\data\\covid\\")
[1] "C:/R/data/covid/"
```

のように”\\”と書くと、内部では”\”と見なされますので、これで正解です。

Comment: ゆえにソースコード上の記述 `"C:\R\data\covid\"` は誤りであるわけです。誤っているソースコードが動かないのは当然ですよね。